# Common Gate Transimpedance Amplifier Transfer Function

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, common-gate

I am trying to find the transfer function of the common gate transimpedance amplifier.
The transfer function that I got is different than the one at the original [publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8988295) even though it leads to the same DC gain.
There is no derivation in the publication, only final result, as I copied in my post below. So, I think it is just fine not reading the original manuscript.

I am aware that the transfer function can be different depending on the assumption used. looking at the result from the publication, it does not ignore \$ r_{o} \$.

Am I missing something here?

This is the diagram:

[image: cg tia]
[image: small signal]

From observation:
$$ v_{s1} = \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}i_{1} $$
$$ v_{out} = \left(R_{D} || \frac{1}{sC_o} \right) (i_{pd} - i_{1}) $$
$$ i_{1} = i_{pd} - \frac{v_{out}}{\frac{R_{D}}{sC_{o}R_{D}+1}}     $$
$$ \left( v_{s1} - v_{out} \right) = (i_{pd} - i_{1} + g_{m}v_{gs1})r_{o} $$
$$ v_{gs1} = \left(0 - \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}i_{1} \right) $$

From equations above, we can solve for \$ v_{out}/i_{pd} \$ by eliminating \$ v_{s1}, v_{gs1}, i_{1} \$.

Two checkpoints are written here:

$$ \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}i_{1} - v_{out} = \left[ i_{pd} - \left( i_{pd} - \frac{v_{out}}{\frac{R_{D}}{sC_{o}R_{D}+1}} \right)   +g_{m} \left( - \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}i_{1} \right)  \right] r_{o} $$

$$ v_{out} \left(1 + \frac{(sC_{o}R_{D} + 1)r_{o}}{R_{D}}  \right) = \left( \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}  + g_{m} \frac{1}{sC_{PD}}r_{o} \right) \left( i_{pd} - \frac{v_{out}}{\frac{R_{D}}{sC_{o}R_{D}+1}} \right) $$

At the end, I got this:

$$ \frac{v_{out}}{i_{pd}} = \frac{(1 + g_{m}r_{o})R_{D}}
{sC_{PD}R_{D} + \left[ (sC_{o}R_{D} + 1)(sC_{PD}r_{o} + g_{m}r_{o} +1 ) \right]   }$$

From the publication, this is the transfer function:

[image]

Comment: The linked Article is behind a pay-wall (ieeexplore) so inaccessible to many of us. Probably the publication does apply some simplifications, for example \$Z(O)_{TIA} = R_D\$ That sounds to me like the output impedance is **only** \$R_D\$ which means that it is assumed that the MOSFET has an infinite output impedance. So from that I would conclude that \$r_o\$ **is** ignored.

Comment: yes, I know it is behind paywall :( I am sure the \$ r_o \$ is not ignored because it is there in the final equation from the publication. it is written as \$ r_{on} \$. There is no derivation in the publication, only final result, as I copied in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the reason or the assumption used in the paper.
The assumption is
$$ R_{D}r_{o} \approx R_{D}(r_{o} + R_{D})$$ for $$  r_{o} >> R_{D} $$

Continuing from my result above.
$$ \frac{v_{out}}{i_{pd}} = \frac{(1 + g_{m}r_{o})R_{D}}
{sC_{PD}R_{D} + \left[ (sC_{o}R_{D} + 1)(sC_{PD}r_{o} + g_{m}r_{o} +1 ) \right]   }$$

the denumerator can be written fully as follow:
$$s^2C_{o}R_{D}C_{PD}r_{o} + s (C_{PD}R_{D} + C_{PD}r_{o} + C_{o}R_{D}g_{m}r_{o} + C_{o}R_{D}) + (g_{m}r_{o} +1)  $$

then when we want to factor it, it can be written as

$$ \left(sC_{o}R_D + 1 \right) \left[ sC_{PD}(r_{o}+ {\color{brown} R_{D} } ) + g_{m1}r_{o} + 1 \right] $$

The additional  \$ {\color{brown} R_{D}} \$ is intentionally added to make factorization easy.
In my case, \$ {\color{brown} R_{D}} \$ is ~5% of \$ r_{o} \$. So it does not affect too much.